# How to hide a file in android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app.It is a simple file manager.We thought of adding a "hide file" feature in the app.So my question is how to hide a file in android?And how to open an hidden file?

Comment: If I remember well my UNIX lessons, you simply have to add a dot (**.**) before the file name, to hide it. Something like `.hidden.txt`

Comment: You may wish to explain what it you mean by "hide a file".

Comment: Have you ever used applock? it is an app in android.You can hide a file using that app.The hidden file wont be seen by the file manager or any of the media players.The file can only be opened in the applock app after providing the password.This is what i am asking for

Answer (score 2):

Files that begin with . are hidden. So just add a dot at the beginning of the file name to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean with a hidden file??

Easy way to *hide* to public users [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

> "Hiding your files from the Media Scanner
>
> Include an empty file named **.nomedia** in your external files directory
>   (**note the dot prefix in the filename**). This will prevent Android's
>   media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps
>   like Gallery or Music."